# How to make 3D models for a game that looks high-poly but has a low poly mesh?

Tags: polycount

I'm new to blender and have followed a bunch of tutorials for the last few weeks. I've gone from knowing nothing about 3D modeling to been able to complete the Donut tutorial by Blender Guru, with some awesome results.

The reason why I wanted to learn blender is because I wanted to make a skin for my favourite game called Depth. And of course I didn't just wanna re-texture an existing model, no I want to make a whole new model becasue me I guess...

Making a model wasn't the hard part and I managed to make a model that I'm really liking. However as I ventured down this path I soon realised that I have to take the poly count to consideration...
I've talked to a seasoned skin maker in this game community who told me I need to "quad draw" in order to make a low poly model and then somehow fuse the low with the high poly model. Sadly as he's not using blender himself I couldn't get more help than that. Found It hard to find good tutorials on this subject specially those that use blender, so my question is:

Anyone who knows good tutorials that have a detailed information on how to make 3D models made for games and what I need to do to "quad draw" and fuse models together?

Additional question while I'm at it. For this game I need to export an FBX 2014 file. are there any addons that allows me to export this version of FBX?

Thanks in advance for any help or responses!

Comment: hi :) You need to be looking for tutorials for Baking High poly model to Low poly model, This process will give you a Normal map texture. Also look for Baking  textures from the high poly model to low poly model. Lots of new things to learn.

Comment: From what understood from this guy I've been talking to theres a lot more than I expected but I really wanna learn so I'm ready to put in the work. I will look into that thanks for the reply! ^^